# Read Large Textfile with Ajax/jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, out-of-memory

i have a 10MB text file and i want to read/load the content of the text file with an ajax call. But when I do this, the browser crashes cause the browser is out of memory. Can someone help me?

This is what i got:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "file.txt",
  success: function (data){
     console.log(data); // it doesn't end up here, browser crashes
  }
});
```

Comment: Please supply a minimal and verifiable code example. What did you try so far?

Comment: 10MB is not a big file and unless your computer is already being starved for resources, loading a file this size should not cause an OOM crash.

Comment: Maybe this can help you out https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: you can read content of text file in one shot...

Comment: @DomenikReitzner i edit my post

Comment: @NegiRox no i cant cause the browser crashes. The txt file is too big too load it in one shot

Comment: It could be useful if you provide some info about the environment here: have you tested with different browsers? Which operating system? Is it a sytem crash of the browser of is it just hanging? You also should test the output differently, as sending 10MB text to the console can be overwhelming (specially on some browsers where console is far from efficient with large text display, when not simply buggued)

Comment: Put some code demo here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code it will not harm your browser. your file is text file. i checked with 10.2 MB file and it is working as expected.

```
  $(function () {
        var myAjax= {
            init: function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "abc.txt",//or path of your file 
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#data1").text(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        myAjax.init();
    });
<div id="data1"></div>
```